# How to set up Global Navigation to link to page with list of pages with that metadata tag?

Tags: enterprise-wiki, global-navigation, categories

I am using SharePoint 2013 and working on a enterprise wiki site. And I have set my global navigation to Managed Navigation using the metadata term set.

Clicking on the tabs in the global navigation currently brings me to a page I have linked/or a new page. I would like it to bring me to a page that lists all the sites that has that metadata tag (like image below). How can I do so?

[image]

Comment: Your second paragraph is confusing me. You want to be redirected to a page that have all the same tags? For example your Global Navigation contains the link "Books" and you want to show a list of all pages that contains the word "Books"? Please guide me if i understood it wrong.

Comment: @MuhammadZeeshanTahir yes that is right!

Comment: Alright. I am posting a possible solution for this problem. Hope that helps you.

Answer (score 0):

To achieve this, first you need a Search Service Application in your farm (no need to recreate if already exists). Then you have to create a Search Center type site anywhere in your SharePoint site i.e. `http://yoursite/SubSite/Search`. Better if you create under the same web application and site collection with inherited permissions. Now for all of your terms in MetaData set the URL of the term URL Like below for example.

**Term Title** : Books

**Term URL** : `http://yoursite/SubSite/Search/pages/results.aspx?k=Books`

You can replace the word **Books** in above URL with each word you want to search with and change the **Title** too accordingly.

Now clicking on the navigation link **Books** will redirect to a search page that will search for you for the word **Books** used anywhere i.e. pages, documents etc. You can further filter your search in the result page.

If you want a page or item to get searched and show in results on clicking the navigation link, Tag that page or item with specified word and make sure that is get crawled in the search.